# Accounting for study entry date in logistic regression for generating propensity scores

Tags: regression, propensity-scores, time-varying-covariate

I am analyzing 30-day mortality associated with two treatments. I am planning to use IPTW. I would like to account for time in my propensity scores. The study inclusion dates span 15 years, so I would like to account for date of hospital admission (i.e. study entry date) in my score as I think medical practice changes over time could be influencing the propensity to receive one treatment vs. the other. What is the best way to account for this in my model?

Comment: Can you please explain IPTW